# Open Outlook OFT template and populate recipient address

Tags: vb.net, templates, outlook, oft

Working in a Windows Forms application and VB.NET.

I need to pop open an Office "New Message" window, populate the "To" address, and place an OFT template in the body of the message.  I do not need to modify anything in the template.

To open the new message with the template, i could:

```
Diagnostics.Process.Start("MyFile.oft")
```

But this will not help with setting the TO address, or subject.

I also don't want to download any third party add-ons.

Any help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Outlook Object Model and call [Application.CreateItemFromTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220081%28v=office.11%29.aspx). You can then set Subject/To/CC/BCC properties and the Recipients collection on the returned MailItem object.

Comment: This works great, thank you.  Is there any way to make the popup have focus, as it's currently displaying behind all open windows.

Comment: Call MailItem.GetInspector, then call Inspector.Display and Inspector.Activate.

Comment: Thank you, again!  Also found that .Display(true) instead of just .Display() works.